# I am trying to use docker for php5.6 with ngnix but there is a issue in configuration

Tags: php, apache, docker, docker-compose

Hello I need to setup php5.6 on my local machine. Following are the docker-compose.yml file

```
  version: '3'

networks:
  laravel:

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - laravel


  php:
    image: gotechnies/php-5.6-alpine
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - laravel
```

ngnix configuration file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

after running docker-compose up -d command following is the output.

[image]

but when i am trying to access http://localhost:8000 i am unable to render page.

Comment: Why are you specifying a port for PHP Alpine? Do this - http://geekyplatypus.com/dockerise-your-php-application-with-nginx-and-php7-fpm/

Comment: i just copy pasted the file from some where. can you please help me I am using docker for very first time?

Comment: Do you need PHP 5.6, or can you use 7? Read the article I linked.

Comment: the article you share is really good. but i need to configure php 5.6

Comment: Why 5.6? What does it give you that 7 doesn't?

Comment: actually i have to run an old application which is developed in 5.6.

Comment: OK - I am working on a solution for you.

Comment: thank you so much for you help.

Comment: Please add the output of `docker-compose logs` when you access http://localhost:8000/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run PHP5.6 with NGINX you will need to do the following:

Directory layout. All web files go in your local `src/` directory

[image]

For **nginx/default.conf** use the following:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

For **src/index.php** (test to make sure PHP is working)

```
<? echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

For your **docker-compose.yml** I have removed a lot of things that you will not need:

```
version: "3"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
        - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src/:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php

  php:
    image: mikolatero/php5.6-fpm-alpine
    volumes: 
      - ./src/:/var/www/html
```

Execute `docker-compose up`.
Navigate to http://localhost:8080/index.php and you should be greeted with the PHP info page:

[image]

### What Changed?

In this case, I opted for the latest NGINX and located a good image for PHP5.6-FPM and used those for the stack.

For the mounted volumes, I moved the directories into the same context as the Docker Compose file. Not necessary, but maybe more portable when running from a laptop. Your mounted web source may/should be the location of your web repo. I also used the well-know location for the web files in the NGINX image `/var/www/html`

The PHP5.6-FPM is mounted to the same directory as the web source so PHP is available to the files in that directory.

Lastly, I got rid of the `networks` as, unless you have a specific reason, it is not necessary as these images will use the default Docker network.