# Need a complete example of using "php-fpm" and "nginx-proxy" together in Docker

Tags: php, docker, nginx, proxy

I would be *very* obliged if someone would please post a *complete example* of how to set up `php-fpm` with the `nginx-proxy` package in Docker.

I am hoping to find a working example which uses *this* particular container, which tries to "auto-configure itself" to changing conditions.  (But allows for per-vhost additional files.)  "One picture would be worth a thousand words."

Comment: ***Pro tip:*** [Do not act needy and do not say your requirement is urgent](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/1011527). The folks answering questions are volunteers with busy lives, just like yours.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59969099/1011527

Comment: Very well, Jay – I edited the comment as you requested.  Thanks very much for the link ... now, does anyone else out there have an example which actually used the ***nginx-proxy*** container?  (Which is supposed to do a lot of configuration "automagically" ...)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Jay's pointer (to stackoverflow.com/q/59969099/1011527) *was* the secret sauce that allowed me to complete this task successfully.  (Many thanks, sir.)

I created a `volume` specification to mount the appropriate configuration parameters (based on Jay's) into `/etc/nginx/vhost.d/domainname.com` (for the appropriate domain-name), repeating this process for each virtual domain.  The default parameters provided at this time by `nginx-proxy` do omit some important settings such as `SCRIPT_FILENAME`.

As I've noted in other recent questions that I've recently raised here, the behavior of the nginx proxy was at times very strange when things weren't "just" right.  Not merely `5xx` errors, but sometimes "no errors at all, and no output."

It would of course be very nice if `nginx-proxy` could in the future be enhanced to make things "as easy as they probably could be," minimizing or avoiding the need to do this, but the bottom line for me is that *it did work (finally!)* using this approach.